# How to automate a text message?

Tags: java, html, api, htmlunit

I have a group that needs to send out announcements and current events via phone text message. I want to have a central phone number that when it receives a text message, it rebroadcasts that message to a growing list of subscribers. I'm hoping to use a Google Voice number to avoid buying an actual phone number.

Any ideas? I've thought about some type of Java/HTMLunit that continually parses the GVoice html inbox, but I just have that computer-gut feeling that there is a more intuitive way. I haven't been able to find a GVoice API, as I imagine that would be the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a different approach.  There's a number of E-mail to SMS services out there.  So you send an e-mail (using standard JavaMail) to a specific address that is then associated with mobile phone numbers.  I use [TextMagic](http://www.textmagic.com/), but there are also other similar services out there. They also have API support, if thats what you'd prefer.